# How to avoid QNetworkAccessManager multiple POST requests?

Tags: qt, networking, qt-creator, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I have implemented post request for my application that looks like this:

```
QNetworkRequest req;
QUrl url = "Http://" + ipaddress + "/goform/executeSomething";
req.setUrl(url);

QHttpMultiPart * postBody = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType, this);
QHttpPart part;
part.setRawHeader("Content-Disposition","form-data; name=\"action\"");
part.setBody("Action");
postBody->append(part);

req.setRawHeader("Authorization","Basic " + credentials);
req.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + postBody->boundary());

nam->post(req,postBody);
```

and signal/slot initialization

```
this->nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(this->nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

On server, there is an error which creates bad HTML, but action itself is correctly executed (if called once). Because of bad HTML in POST response, QNetworkAccessManager retries its POST request couple of times (usually 3 or 4 can be seen in Wireshark). In Qt, replyFinished is reached only once, immediately after last POST in Wireshark. NetworkReply contains "Connection closed" error.

Problem here is that when posted action is executed few times in a row, it does bad things on server. As I don't have access on server side, I am looking for a solution on client side that will invoke POST method just once. Is there any parameter that can be set in QNetworkAccessManager that will allow only single POST attemp? Or is there any alternative in Qt that can be used instead?

Comment: `QNetworkAccessManager` knows nothing about 'bad html' in the response. All it does is just sending a HTTP request and receiving a response.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to the QNetworkReply signals instead of the QNetworkAccessManager:

```
QNetworkReply* l_reply = nam->post(req,postBody);
connect(l_reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(replyFinished()));
connect(l_reply, error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(replyError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));  // good practice
```

then, in the slot *replyFinished* you can retrieve the reply in this way:

```
QNetworkReply* l_reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
if(l_reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
   ....
else
   qDebug() << l_reply.readAll();  // assign this to a variable or it will be lost once you print it
```